# Detecting when an EC2 instance will be shutting down (Java SDK)

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I posted this on the AWS support forums but haven't received a response, so hoping you guys have an idea...

We have an auto-scaling group which boots up or terminates an instance based on current load. What I'd like to be able to do it detect, on my current EC2 instance, that it's about to be shut down and to finish my work.

To describe the situation in more detail. We have an auto-scaling group, and each instance reads content from a single SQS. Each instance will be running multiple threads, each thread is reading from the same SQS queue and processing the data as needed.

I need to know when this instance will be about to shut down, so I can stop new threads from reading data, and block the shutdown until the remaining data has finished processing.

I'm not sure how I can do this in the Java SDK, and I'm worried my instances will be terminated without my data being processed correctly.

Thanks
Lee

Comment: Have you looked at [Runtime.addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) ?

Comment: I haven't really looked at anything yet as I simply didn't know where to start. A shutdown hook might be feasible but I suspect I'll be in situations where my running process takes to long (the docs indicate that's a bad thing) and aws will terminate the instance before its done.  I suspect I need a notification from AWS that a shutdown is about to happen and somehow I tell it to wait.

Comment: Hmm, you may want to have the shutdown method perform a "check" on the instance in question to see if it's ready to be shutdown, first. If you have a database that you're accessing (like DynamoDB, for example) you could simply pass triggers through a special table made for the instances, otherwise you could try opening a socket between the 2 instances to communicate that the remote instance is done. To my knowledge, the shutdown performed does whatever it takes to shutdown, so I'm unaware of any way to interrupt or delay it once it's initiated. Stuck programs are simply terminated on shutdown.

Comment: if it is an linux (Debain) instances u could write a shell script for which could send u an email before termination by setting traps in it, link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599500/shell-script-that-send-email-before-exiting

Answer (score 1):

When it wants to scale down, AWS Auto Scaling will terminate your EC2 instances without warning.

There's no way to allow any queue workers to drain before terminating.

If your workers are processing messages transactionally, and you're not deleting messages from SQS until after they have been successfully processed, then this shouldn't be a problem. The processing will stop when the instance is terminated, and the transaction will not commit. The message won't be deleted from the SQS queue, and can be picked up and processed by another worker later on.

The only kind of draining behavior it supports is HTTP connection draining from an ELB: ["If connection draining is enabled for your load balancer, Auto Scaling waits for the in-flight requests to complete or for the maximum timeout to expire, whichever comes first, before terminating instances".](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html)